# Making a relationship ordered causes "Dangling reference to an invalid object.” error while using context confinement

Tags: ios, core-data, ios5

After trying out AFIncrementalStore I've decided to do most of the work manually to have more control over what happens and when.

Object structure I have looks like this. "products" relationship is an ordered one.

[image]

Here's the code that runs inside a NSOperation

```
NSManagedObjectContext* childContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType: NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
childContext.parentContext = self.parentManagedObjectContext;
[childContext performBlockAndWait: ^
{
    DashboardViewModel* dashboardViewModel = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"DashboardViewModel"
                                                                           inManagedObjectContext: childContext];
    NSMutableOrderedSet* products = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithCapacity: productRepresentations.count];
    for (NSDictionary* rawProductRepresentation in productRepresentations)
    {
        Product* product = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Product"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext: childContext];
        product.dashboardViewModel = dashboardViewModel;
        [products addObject: product];
    }

    dashboardViewModel.products = products;


    NSError* saveError = nil;
    if (![childContext save: &saveError])
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", saveError);

    //Save parent context to push changes to persistent store
    [self.parentManagedObjectContext performBlock: ^
    {
        NSError* saveParentError = nil;
        if (![childContext.parentContext save: &saveParentError])
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", saveParentError);
    }];
}];
```

Seems correct to me but I always get an error when saving parent context that says "Dangling reference to an invalid object.”

Any suggestions?

Comment: May not be related to your error, but you shouldn't have to set both sides of the relationship. Core data sets the reverse half of the relationship for you, so you could remove your `products` set and just rely on setting `product.dashboardViewModel = dashboardViewModel`.

Comment: @dokkaebi Please post this as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to set both sides of the relationship. Core data sets the reverse half of the relationship for you, so you could remove your `products` set and just rely on setting `product.dashboardViewModel = dashboardViewModel`.